# How to connect and get the balance from a Metamask wallet on the Polygon chain in React.js

Tags: reactjs, polygon, metamask

What is the best way to do the following actions on a DAAP developed with React.js?

Actions:

- connect/disconnect... on Metamask wallet
- get accounts
- get balance on MATIC from this account
- get ERC720 tokens from this account

Minimum requirements (objetives):

- built-in on react.js
- just need metamask integration
- need to run on the Polygon chain network

I am very confused becasue I have tried a lot of libraries like web3.js, ether.js, web3-react... and I did not find a proper solution. Anyone can ilustrate me and tell me the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic metamask functions to connect with metamask and getting the account details, and for balance part you can either use the web3 calls from [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/) library or for ease use the [maticjs library](https://maticnetwork.github.io/matic.js/docs/get-started) from polygon. Writing this quick snippet for fetching balance using maticjs. Checkout the full POC for react DApp at https://github.com/ankitboghra/polygon-dapp-poc

```
import { POSClient, use } from "@maticnetwork/maticjs"
import { Web3ClientPlugin } from '@maticnetwork/maticjs-web3'

use(Web3ClientPlugin)

await posClient.init({
      network: networkName,  // 'testnet' or 'mainnet'
      version: networkVersion, // 'mumbai' or 'v1'
      parent: {
        provider: mainProvider,
        defaultConfig: {
          from: currentAccount
        }
      },
      child: {
        provider: maticProvider,
        defaultConfig: {
          from: currentAccount
        }
      }
    });


const erc20Token = posClient.erc20(tokenAddress, false);
const balance = await erc20Token.getBalance(currentAccount)
```